# Why doesnt my function run on .resize()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a function to center my `<div>` using jQuery, it works on page load but doesn't on page resize.

What am I doing wrong?

**JS:**

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        function reCenter() {
            $('.content').css({
                position:'absolute',
                left: ($(window).width() 
                    - $('.content').outerWidth())/2,
                top: ($(window).height() 
                    - $('.content').outerHeight())/2
            });             
        }
        $(window).resize(reCenter());
        // To initially run the function:
        reCenter();
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <span class="hyphen">-</span>
    <h2>Subtext</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html { 
            background: darkgrey;
        }
        body {
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            /*padding-top: 300px;*/
        }
        h1 {
            font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 40px;
        }
        span.hyphen {
            color: #0CFFFC;
            font-size: 3em;
        }
h2 {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 100;


        }
```

**UPDATE**
After getting the function to fire up on page load, it has some inconsistent behaviour between page load  and window resize
http://jsfiddle.net/7zqkd4w8/

Comment: If your content isn't dynamic, you can try using the methods [here](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html), which centers a block both vertically and horizontally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `$(window).resize(reCenter);` since you are sending it a function not the results of calling the function.

Comment: When I do this, on resize the function is called but now the function isn't called when page loads. I have tried changing the last line to `reCenter;` but this does not work either.

Comment: Keep the last line as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find width of '.content' div. You won't get proper width of the div unless its floating or absolute. You are giving absolute class to .content in reCenter(); so if you trigger your resize function twice(on first time) it would work.

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
   reCenter()
}).resize().resize();
```

But suggested method to do it is just add float left to the content and your existing code should work.

```
.content{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
   reCenter()
}).resize();//triggers on first page load
```